# Add class to active page does not work for pages in sub folders

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have the following script that add a class .active to the current page:

```
//Main menu .active classes handler
    $("#mainMenu a").filter(function () {
        var href = location.href.replace(/#*/, "");
        if (location.pathname === "/") {href += "index";}
        return href === this.href;
    }).addClass("active");
```

Everything works fine for the pages in the main directory but it does not work for the pages in sub folders, for example:

It works for `<a href="index.php">Home</a>` but it won't work for: `<a href="sub/test.php">Home</a>` **Why is that?** Do I need to add something like "last of index"?

Full HMTL:

```
<li><a href="index">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="about">About</a></li>
<li class="subMenu"><a href="gallery">Gallery</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="sub/test">Page in a sub folder</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="contact">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: What does the html look like?

Comment: Just updated he answer adding the HMTL of the links.

Comment: A simple test of a fake location string seems to work fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/77rz9/ but there may be some html/location differences I'm not accounting for. Also, I suggest placing your var href outside the filter, since you only need it set once, not every iteration

Comment: Your sample code/html work fine for me (with a faked location) http://jsfiddle.net/77rz9/1/

Comment: Try `return window.location.href.indexOf( this.getAttribute('href') ) != -1;`

Comment: Hmm, why it does not work for me :/ so does the script above read the page that is after the last /?

Comment: I suggest you throw a console.log in your code and find out what the values for `location` and `href` are. Your equality condition is failing, so there's a cause somewhere. In my example code I faked the location since it's jsfiddle but the code works as intended. I don't recommend the indexOf approach, there's a chance you could have similar paths that might be false positives

Comment: As a sidenote, what is `/#*/` supposed to match?

Comment: @BotskoNet please take a live preview here: http://loaistudio.com/testing/test

Comment: @adeneo I don't know my self :/ I don't know what this bit does.

Comment: It just does not apply the class active to any page that is inside sub folder...

Answer (score 1):

The error isn't in your code, but rather the fact that you're including the site javascript using relative paths:

When you visit `/testing/test` the javascript files return as `404` because they're relative.

`assets/js/main.js` becomes `/testing/test/assets/js/main.js`

Just use absolute paths or you can look into setting the [base href](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)

You should use a developer console like Firebug or Chrome dev tools to watch for any errors. I immediately saw 404 errors and noticed it was your js file.

Comment: Oh, so I basically need to add "/" before any link etc?

Comment: Right. that will be absolute to the domain so domain.com/assets/etc

Comment: I just want to avoid adding the domain name on front to send the link back to the root

Comment: Absolute paths are relative to the domain only, not the folder/path you're visiting. `/page` = `http://domain.com/page`

Comment: I am really sorry, please can you explain a bit more? please mate

Comment: I know that / will go back to the root folder. but for me it does not

Comment: I just tried to use: `<?php include $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/assets/includes/header.inc"; ?>` for some bazaar reason it works for some and not for most :/

Comment: Just use `<script src="/assets/js/main.js"></script>` - leaving out the beginning forward-slash would make this url relative - meaning appended to the current URL. if the url is `domain.com/subfolder` the path would be treated as `domain.com/subfolder/assets/etc..` but that's not where your files are.

Comment: I understand the problem now and what you are trying to say. Adding the domain name before the URL's will solve the problem - but there is no other way? I really don't want to add the domain name before every include and url - please help

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46550/discussion-between-loai-and-botskonet)

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by adding `<base href="/">` in my head. It works like magic!